# Restrict dropPosotion before and after Kendo UI treeview

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

When doing drag and drop in Kendo UI TreeView it has 3 positions namely "before", "over" and "after".

> http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#dragend

Is it possible to restrict the "before" and "after" states and only allow drop "over" functionality.

**Note**

> *In my scenario I have 2 trees and I'm dragging element from left tree to the other.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `kendoTreeView`, define `drag` and `drop` event handlers as follow:

```
drag       : function (ev) {
    if (!$(ev.dropTarget).hasClass("k-in k-state-hover")) {
        ev.setStatusClass("k-denied")
    }
},
drop       : function (ev) {
    if (ev.sourceNode === ev.destinationNode) {
        ev.setValid(false);
    }
}
```

In the `drag` I check that we are *over* an element and if not I set that status class to `k-denied` that it formats the `clue` as denied but also prevents from dropping it there.

In the `drop` I just check that I'm not dropping on top of itself preventing a stack overflow.

Running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mu92b/

Comment: Your code works for a single tree. But in my scenario I have 2 trees and I'm dragging element from left tree to the other.

Comment: This solutions works for two trees as well and moving elements from one tree to another. See it running here (http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mu92b/1/). What it does not control is that you are moving from tree1 to tree2 and not viceversa or inside the same tree. Is that what you want to control?

Comment: Version allowing only from tree1 over element of tree2: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/eyjTN/

Comment: Minor thing: this code doesn't cater for having icons as tree nodes. I have folder icons as tree nodes and when I drag one folder over another folder icon, the drag status shows denied, when I hover the text of the node, it's OK

Comment: In fact, warning, this code is a little dodgy in that it also doesn't cater for the node dragged onto being selected - eg "k-state-selected" on the node. So I would replace the hasClass() which combines k-in and k-state-hover (a hard-coded, not-always-the-case scenario) with an if statement that AND's the condition with the desired states

Comment: I ended up adding code like this to check whether it was inserting (as per Kendo's own demos) - if (e.statusClass.indexOf("insert") >= 0) to determine "are we not over an element" or in other words "are we inserting" - which while not perfect, seems much clearer